# What does DOA stand for?

Tags: p2pool, terminology, mining-pool-shares

What does DOA stand for?

I've seen this in the context of [P2Pool](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/P2Pool) stales, specifically [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/P2Pool#Tips_to_configure_bfgminer_to_reduce_stale.2Fdoa:).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dead On Arrival. The term is referring to about valid shares your miner discovers that were found too late to be included in the P2Pool internal block chain and therefor aren't paid to the miner. Counter intuitively a DOA share can still be a valid Bitcoin block.